# Laravel OrWhere orWhereHas slowing down the application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

The following code checks the whether subscriber can access the property or not.

If property subscriber_id == current subscriber id, can access it.

If property subscriber_id within linked offices subscriber id, can access it.

Elseif property table auction_booked_by or presentations table auction_booked_by equals to subscriber, can access it.

I have used the orWhere and orWhereHas in query builder. I am getting data but it takes more than 7 to 8 secs. With out orWhereHas, taking only 2 to 3 secs. What would be the solution?

Here is my full code to get property data:
$this->model is Property model.
And Property belongs to many presentations.

```
$currentSubscriber = Auth::user()->subscriber_id;
$linkedOfficesSubscribers = Auth::user()->subscriber->getLinkedAgencyIdsAttribute();
$subscriberIds = $linkedOfficesSubscribers->merge($currentSubscriber);
$sidewaysSubscriberIds = Auth::user()->subscriber->getSidewaysAgenciesIdsAttribute();
$query = $this->model
    ->join('subscribers', 'properties.subscriber_id', '=','subscribers.id')
    ->join('property_auction_details', 'property_auction_details.property_id', '=','properties.id')
    ->leftjoin('property_listing_details','property_listing_details.property_id', '=','properties.id')
    ->with('subscriber')
    ->whereIn('properties.subscriber_id', $subscriberIds)
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($sidewaysSubscriberIds) {
        $query->whereIn('properties.subscriber_id', $sidewaysSubscriberIds)
            ->where('properties.auction_booked_by', Auth::user()->subscriber_id)
            ->orWhereHas('presentations', function ($query) {
                $query->where('presentations.auction_booked_by', Auth::user()->subscriber_id);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentSubscriber = Auth::user()->subscriber_id;
$linkedOfficesSubscribers = Auth::user()->subscriber->getLinkedAgencyIdsAttribute();
$subscriberIds = $linkedOfficesSubscribers->merge($currentSubscriber);
$sidewaysSubscriberIds = Auth::user()->subscriber->getSidewaysAgenciesIdsAttribute();

$query = $this->model
    ->join('subscribers', 'properties.subscriber_id', '=', 'subscribers.id')
    ->join('property_auction_details', 'property_auction_details.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
    ->leftJoin('property_listing_details', 'property_listing_details.property_id', '=', 'properties.id')
    ->whereIn('properties.subscriber_id', $subscriberIds)
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($sidewaysSubscriberIds, $currentSubscriber) {
        $query->where('properties.auction_booked_by', $currentSubscriber)
            ->whereIn('properties.subscriber_id', $sidewaysSubscriberIds);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('presentations', function ($query) use ($currentSubscriber) {
        $query->where('presentations.auction_booked_by', $currentSubscriber);
    })
    ->with('subscriber') // Eager loading
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have edited a bit in my question and code. @akshay-ak Can you please have a look? orWhereHas is playing critical role in the query. That's slowing down.

Comment: I have edited the code , try if it helps